# Invoking a rest API written in java from go code

Tags: rest, go

I am newbie to Golang.
I am writing a go client, in which I am trying to invoke a bunch of REST APIs in server

Which rest clients/libraries should be used for this use case

Thanks!

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: Have you tried anything or done a basic web search? Accessing REST APIs is a very common use case and there is plentiful documentation available.

Comment: @Adrian I know the net/http route, but wondering if there is a third party library on top of that

Comment: Wondering about third-party libraries is off-topic for SO: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: That said, do you have something against `net/http`? There's no real reason to put anything on top of it.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for the guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang comes with native `"net/http"` package which you can use to request REST APIs